# splunk - create chart with values function

Tags: charts, continuous-integration, performance-testing, splunk

Background: Soon after my performance test, the response time details of the business transactions will be fed into splunk, from where I need to generate trend graph for couple of transactions for certain period of time.
Now I am able to group the response time data for these transactions but in visualization, not able to generate the chart.

Refer:SS01.jpg for more details.

[image]

query used: index=xyz source=abc (Period!=Period) Transaction_Name=Search OR Address_Book OR Policy | chart values(Average) as Average by Transaction_Name

I want the chart to appear in either format A or B as it appears on SS02.jpg.

[image]

Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have very low values (i.e. `0.046`, `0.099`, etc) in the query output and very high value in the chart Y axis (`100`), in order to get the desired picture just reduce the maximum value for the vertical axis like:

[image: Splunk reduce maximum Y axis]

To make the changes permanent you can amend `charting.secondaryAxis.maximumNumber` parameter value like it described in [Controlling chart (y axis) range](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/22892/controlling-chart-y-axis-range.html)

Personally I prefer [BM.Sense](http://sense.blazemeter.com/) output for performance test results analysis.